# Defining compact sets with closed covers

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness, proof-explanation

This question is a continuation of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1837783/compact-metric-space-definition-by-closed-covers). My book says that a metric space is compact if and only if:

$$M=\cup A_{\lambda}\implies M = A_{\lambda1}\cup\cdots\cup A_{\lambda_n}$$

where each $A_{\lambda}$ is open. Then, it says that the definition can be extended to closed sets, since if $A_\lambda$ is a family of open sets in $M$, then the complements $F_\lambda = F-A_\lambda$ forms a family of closed sets in $M$. We have, then: 
$$M=\cup A_\lambda\iff \cap F_\lambda = \emptyset.$$
So, by the last question, I understood the reason behind this. No problem. The book then proceeds:

> A metric space $M$ is compact, $\iff$ all families
>   $(F_\lambda)_{\lambda\in L}$ of closed sets with empty intersection
>   has a finite subfamily with empty intersection: $F_{\lambda_1}\cap
> \cdots \cap F_{\lambda_n}=\emptyset$.

Then, the book proceeds and says:

> A family $(F_\lambda)_{\lambda\in L}$ has the **property of finite
>   intersection** when for any finite subset $\{\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_n
>  \}\subset L$ we have $F_{\lambda_1}\cap\cdots\cap F_{\lambda_n}\neq
>  \emptyset$.
>
> The following condition is necessary and sufficient to tell that a
>   metric space $M$ is compact:
>
> If $(F_\lambda)_{\lambda\in L}$ if a family of closed sets with the
>   **property of finite intersection**, then $\cap_{\lambda\in L}F_\lambda
>  \neq \emptyset$

Is the last one the negation of the first one? I mean, for $M$ to be compact, either we have:

**family of closed sets with empty intersection has finite subfamily with empty intersection**

or

**family of closed sets with the property of finite intersection (that is, every intersection of finite subfamilies is not empty) does not have a empty intersection.**

Is this correct?

I ask this, because the book proceeds for a **proof of Dini's theorem** like this:

> An example of a family of closed subsets with the property of finite
>   intersection is a decrescent sequence $F_1\supset F_2\supset
>  \cdots\supset F_n\supset \cdots$ of nonempty closed subsets of $M$. If
>    $M$ is compact, it follows that $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}F_n\neq
>  \emptyset$. The following demonstration shows these ideas:
>
> **Dini's theorem**: If a sequence of continuous real functions $f_n:M\to
>  \mathbb{R}$ defined in a compact metric space $M$, converges simply to
>   a function $f:M\to \mathbb{R}$, and if $f_1(x)\le f_2(x)\le \cdots\le
>  f_n(x)\le \cdots$ for all $x\in M$, then the convergence $f_n\to f$ is
>   uniform in $M$.
>
> Demonstration: Given $\epsilon>0$, choose, for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$:
>
> $$F_n=\{x\in M: |f_n(x)-f(x)|\ge \epsilon\}$$
>
> Then, $F_1\supset F_2\supset \cdots \supset F_n\supset \cdots$ and
>   each $F_n$ is closed in $M$. We must prove that there is $n_0\in
>  \mathbb{N}$ such that $F_{n_0}=\emptyset$ (then $n>n_0\implies
>  |f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x\in M$). Well, since $\lim_{n\to
>  \infty} f_n(x)=f(x)$ for all $x\in M$, it follows that
>    $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} F_n = \emptyset$ (**WHY?**). Being $M$ compact, we must have  $F_n=\emptyset$ for some $n$

And besides the chain of sets $F_1\supset F_2\supset \cdots \supset F_n\supset \cdots$ having the property of finite intersection (every subfamily has a not empty intersection), the proof concludes that $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}F_n = \emptyset$

Comment: Your two bolded statements are contrapositive to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have two questions, one of which I addressed in a comment.  The other is how to justify the statement

> Since $\lim_{n\to
>  \infty} f_n(x)=f(x)$ for all $x\in M$, it follows that
>    $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} F_n =\emptyset$

Note that
$$
\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty F_n = 
\left\{x \in M : |f_n(x) - f(x)| \geq \epsilon  \text{ for all } n\right\}
$$
However, if $x$ is such that $f_n(x) \to f(x)$, then (by definition of convergence) $x$ is not an element of this set.  So, if $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ for every $x \in M$, then $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty F_n = \emptyset$.

Comment: I'd recommend to include the information from the comment in the answer as well.

Comment: ok, now, in the end, it says that being $M$ compact, we must have $F_n=\emptyset$ for some $n$. Why? And which one of the bolded definitions it's using? I ask because in the beggining, it says that the chain of descending closed sets has the property of finite intersection, that is, any subfamily of them has a not empty intersection. How is it possible to conclude that the intersection IS empty?

Comment: The statement in the end follows directly from the first of your bolded definitions.  As I stated, however, the two bolded definitions are equivalent, since they are contrapositives of one another.  That is, if we find that the total intersection is empty, then the collection **can't** satisfy the finite intersection property.  We used the infinite intersection to conclude that there exists a satisfactory finite intersection.